# Calculating count and average with MongoDB aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a simple db layout like this:

```
client
    id
    sex (male/female)
    birthday (date)    

client
    id
    sex (male/female)
    birthday (date)  

(...)
```

I'm trying to write an aggregation command that outputs how many male and female clients I've got, and I'd also like to output the average age of males and females, not sure I can do this in the same command or I need 2 separate ones?

```
// Count of males/females, average age
Clients.aggregate({
    $project : {"sex"      : 1,
            "sexCount" : 1,
            "birthday" : 1,
            "avgAge"   : 1
               } 
    },
    {
        $match: {"sex": {$exists: true}} 
    },
    {
        $group: {
                    _id      : "$sex",
            sexCount : { $sum: 1 },
            avgAge   : { $avg: "$birthday" },
            }
    },
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } }
    , function(err, sex_dbres) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            else{
                (...)
            }
        });
```

With the code above I get the counts of male/female, but avgAge comes as 0. Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: note that you don't need to project the fields sexCount or avgAge in the first step as those are the fields you will calculate in the $group step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date object can't be "averaged", but numbers can. You can convert your dates to the timestamp value, and then find average from it. But still that won't be an average age, you'll need to subtract result from the current date outside of the aggregation function.

Another option is to assume that age can be calculated using only year part of the date (that is, if I was born on December 1, 2000, in today's report I'll be 12 years old, not 11). In this case you can use [date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#date-operators) to extract year value.

```
$project : {"sex"      : 1,
            "sexCount" : 1,
            "year" : {$year: "$birthday"},
           } 
},
$project : {"sex"      : 1,
            "sexCount" : 1,
            "age" : {$subtract: [2012, '$year']},
           } 
},
```

Comment: Thanks. Just realized that Birthday is stored as string ("Sat May 22 1982 00:00:00 GMT+0200") which makes things a bit more difficult. Is it possible to cast it as a number? I've tried doing a substr to get just the year part but then I'm having trouble turning that into a number to then do the $subtract you propose.
If this is difficult then I guess I can turn the field into a date.

Comment: The conversion is not part of aggregation framework, I guess you'll either need to use MapReduce where you can write arbitrary javascript code, or run through your database and convert all dates.

Comment: Thank you! I extracted the year into a separate field and now can easily do the average.

Answer (score 6):

The answer would be much simpler if you were storing age in the original document (as Dmitry posted, you could just do a straight `avgAge:{$avg:"$age"}` in your `$group` step.

Aggregation Framework is pretty nifty though and has many cool operators which allow you to compute this missing age field "on the fly".

I'm going to store each step of the aggregation in a variable so it's easier to see what's going on:

```
today = new Date();
// split today and bday into numerical year and numerical day-of-the-year
project1= {
    "$project" : {
        "sex" : 1,
        "todayYear" : {
            "$year" : today
        },
        "todayDay" : {
            "$dayOfYear" : today
        },
        "by" : {
            "$year" : "$bday"
        },
        "bd" : {
            "$dayOfYear" : "$bday"
        }
    }
};
// calculate age in days by subtracting bday in days from today in days
project2 = {
    "$project" : {
        "sex" : 1,
        "age" : {
            "$subtract" : [
                {
                    "$add" : [
                        {
                            "$multiply" : [
                                "$todayYear",
                                365
                            ]
                        },
                        "$todayDay"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "$add" : [
                        {
                            "$multiply" : [
                                "$by",
                                365
                            ]
                        },
                        "$bd"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};
// sum up for each sex the count and compute avg age (in days)
group = {
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$sex",
        "total" : {
            "$sum" : 1
        },
        "avgAge" : {
            "$avg" : "$age"
        }
    }
};
// divide days by 365 to get age in years.
project3 = {
    "$project" : {
        "_id" : 0,
        "sex" : "$_id",
        "total" : 1,
        "averageAge" : {
            "$divide" : [
                "$avgAge",
                365
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can run the aggregation:

```
> db.client.find({},{_id:0})
{ "sex" : "male", "bday" : ISODate("2000-02-02T08:00:00Z") }
{ "sex" : "male", "bday" : ISODate("1987-02-02T08:00:00Z") }
{ "sex" : "female", "bday" : ISODate("1989-02-02T08:00:00Z") }
{ "sex" : "female", "bday" : ISODate("1993-11-02T08:00:00Z") }
> db.client.aggregate([ project1, project2, group, project3 ])
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "sex" : "female",
            "total" : 2,
            "averageAge" : 21.34109589041096
        },
        {
            "sex" : "male",
            "total" : 2,
            "averageAge" : 19.215068493150685
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
>
```

The reason this is not simple is currently Aggregation Framework does not support direct subtraction of dates.   Please vote for https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6239 which is targeted for the next major release - once it's implemented it should allow subtraction of dates directly (though you will still need to convert it to appropriate granularity, years in this case probably).

Comment: of course another way to do it could be to convert bday to days, get the avg of those in the group step and in the final project compute age from today in days minus bday in days divided by 365.

Comment: Thanks Asya, similar approach as above.